# How to decide if use [mathematical-astronomy], or just post to astronomy.SE?

Tags: discussion, tagging, allowed-questions

Recently I have asked this question:

[Do all spherically symmetric stellar systems have zero anisotropy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129733/do-all-spherically-symmetric-stellar-systems-have-zero-anisotropy)

I have also asked some other questions in this topic, ie

[Poisson's equation-like formula in axis-symmetric Galactic potential in terms of Oort constants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128201/poissons-equation-like-formula-in-axis-symmetric-galactic-potential-in-terms-of)

[How to transform continuity equation from physical to comoving coordinates (Cosmology)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4085460/how-to-transform-continuity-equation-from-physical-to-comoving-coordinates-cosm)

[How to get mean anomaly as a function of eccentric anomaly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084031/how-to-get-mean-anomaly-as-a-function-of-eccentric-anomaly)

[Is there a name for the point at the intersection of the major axis and a line through a given point in an ellipse parallel with semi latus rectum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084012/is-there-a-name-for-the-point-at-the-intersection-of-the-major-axis-and-a-line-t)

[Parametrized solution for motion of radially infalling object](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083209/parametrized-solution-for-motion-of-radially-infalling-object)

[Deriving the first moment of Collisionless Boltzmann Equation in Spherical Polar Coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968607/deriving-the-first-moment-of-collisionless-boltzmann-equation-in-spherical-polar)

How do I decide if I post my question here with the [mathematical-astronomy] tag, or just use [astronomy.stackexchange.com](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Is your question primarily about the mathematics?  or the astronomy?  If it is primarily about the underlying mathematics, ask here.  Otherwise, ask on [astronomy.se].

Comment: Since you're asking what is on-topic here, I have added ([meta-tag:allowed-questions]). I have also added ([meta-tag:tagging]) - since you mentioned one particular tag - but I am less sure whether (tagging) really belongs here or not. Of course, you (and other users) can edit the tags further, if needed.

Comment: hmm you could perhaps say what's a "a spherically symmetric stellar system" mathematically in your first question.